# pip3 do not install new versions of pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip

I'm in Debian from Google Cloud Instances

```
Linux instance-group-2-67pr 4.9.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.210-1
(2020-01-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm using `pip3` with Python 3.5.3

```
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python
3.5)
```

When I'm trying to install it with `pip3 install pandas==1.0.3` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
pandas==1.0.3 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2b0, 0.2b1, 0.2, 0.3.0b0,
0.3.0b2, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0rc1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 
 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0rc1, 0.8.0rc2, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0rc1 , 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0rc1, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0rc1, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23.0rc2, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.24.0rc1, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 0.25.0rc0, 0.25.0, 0.25.1 , 0.25.2, 0.25.3) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.0.3
```

So you may think that `pip3` doesn't have `pandas version 1.0.3`, but if I type `pip3 search pandas` I get:

```
pandas (1.0.3)                      - Powerful data structures for
data analysis, time series, and statistics
```

I have tried with `venv`, restoring, installing, uninstalling, creating new machines, etc... Nothing works... Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas >= 1.0.0 requres Python 3.6.1 or higher: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html#increased-minimum-version-for-python

Comment: Obviusly! I got confused because pip3 was listing it, but them I read that pip3 is listing all the available libraries not based on your python version... So that makes complete sense.